# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, uid

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

Here is my error message; I have changed the package name, factory reset my debug device, running the command, I have tried all but still my problem is not resolved. What can I do?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Consider editing your question to add more relevant information and format the text.

Comment: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] error occured in android studio

Comment: i got the solution, just change the application id in build.gradle file to any name.